# Vertical scrolling using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I am trying to implement Vertical Scrolling. 
When clicking on the 'down'-div it will move 1 div up and when clicking on the 'up'-div it will move 1 div down.
But it only works on the first click. The user should be able to click down until the last div and then the 'down'-div should be disabled.

HTML:

```
<div id="up">up</div>
<div id="parent">
<div class="child">1</div>
<div class="child">2</div>
<div class="child">3</div>
<div class="child">4</div>
<div class="child">5</div>
<div class="child">6</div>
<div class="child">7</div>
<div class="child">8</div>
<div class="child">9</div>
<div class="child">10</div>
<div class="child">11</div>
</div>
<div id="down">down</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
   width:300px;
   height:288px;
   border:1px solid #000;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.child{
   width:300px;
   height:48px;
   border:1px solid #FF0000;
}
#up{
   width:30px;
   height:20px;
   background-color:#006600;
   cursor:pointer;
}
#down{
   width:40px;
   height:20px;
   background-color:#006600;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $('#down').live("click",function(){
      var scrollval = $('.child').height();
      $('#parent').scrollTop(scrollval);
   });

   $('#up').live("click",function(){
      var scrollval =  $('.child').height();
      $('#parent').scrollTop(-scrollval);
   });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XGXvD/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason it only works on the first click is because you are only ever moving +48px or -48px from the top. You need to +/- the 48 from the current scrollTop value.

So if we're already 96px from the top and we press down, we want to add 48 to 96 like so:

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XGXvD/2/)

```
 $(document).on("click", "#down", function(){
        var scrollval = $('.child').height();
        // this gives us the current scroll position
        var currentscrollval = $('#parent').scrollTop();

        $('#parent').scrollTop(scrollval+currentscrollval);
});
```

Also, note that `.live()` has been depreciated from jQuery 1.7+. You need to use `.on()` like my example (if you are using jQuery 1.7+)

### EDIT - Added Show/Hide buttons functionality

[Updated jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XGXvD/4/)

First, you need to work out some variables. I declared these outside of the click events so they could be used in both functions if needed.

```
// get the number of .child elements
var totalitems = $("#parent .child").length;
// get the height of .child
var scrollval = $('.child').height();
// work out the total height.
var totalheight = (totalitems*scrollval)-($("#parent").height());
```

**Up:**

```
// hide/show buttons
if(currentscrollval == totalheight) {
     $(this).hide();         
 }
 else {
     $("#up").show();
 }
```

**Down:**

```
 // hide/show buttons
 if((scrollval+currentscrollval) == scrollval) {
    $(this).hide();         
 }
 else {
     $("#down").show();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! a lot for your help, and making it look so simple!